# Сертификат для KeyStore

Tags: java, android, безопасность, криптография

Создаю хранилище для PrivateKey. В строке     `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry()` в функцию `PrivateKeyEntry()` необходимо передать 2 параметра один из которых сам приватный ключ, а второй параметр это сертификат. Я не совсем понимаю как этот сертификат получить имея открытый и закрытый ключ.
Весь кусок кода(строку в которой проблема выделил):

```
final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(4096, new SecureRandom());
final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.getText().toString().toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(?????????)

store.setEntry(nickname.getText().toString(), skEntry, protParam);
```

Comment: Нет времени на развернутый ответ, но неплохо расписано тут https://dev64.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/ssl-keystore-java/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по вопросу вы не совсем понимаете основную проблему публичной криптографии. Главная ее проблема состоит в том, чтобы удостовериться, что публичный ключ принадлежит тому кто ее предъявляет.

Это аналогично тому, что человек приходит с ключом от квартиры, <strike>где бабки лежат</strike> и надо теперь удостовериться что это его квартира. В обычной жизни с такого человека затребуют документ подтверждающий что квартира принадлежит ему или по крайней мере он имеет какое-то отношение к ней (например договор аренды).

Точно такую же роль этого удостоверяющего документа в публичной криптографии имеет цифровой сертификат. В реале цифровые сертификаты генерируют доверенные центры, типа VeriSign, Thawte и проч. Их подписи распознаются нормальными браузерами и устройствами, поскольку они могут сверить слепок подписи (fingerprint) со слепками, которые хранятся в устройствах. Для интереса зайдите в своем Android устройстве в раздел *Сертификаты безопасности* - в настройках девайса или в любом настольном браузере в настройках, типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.

Вообще-то сертификация ключа стоит и денег и времени.

В вашем случае, вы сами генерируете на лету пару ключей и поэтому не сможете предъявить нормальный сертификат. На этот случай предусмотрена генерация т.н. *Self Signed Certificate*, то есть сертификата, который вы сами же и подписали своим же ключом. Возвращаясь к нашему примеру с квартирой, это аналог того, что  - предъявитель ключа пишет расписку, типа: *да, я имярек, мамой клянусь, что это моя квартира* :)

Теперь ближе к делу. Вам надо cгенерировать т.н. SelfSigned сертификат стандарта X.509. Но здесь начинаются проблемы. Реализация класса [X509Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) из коробки подразумевает его создания только из битового массива или из `InputStream`, Selfsign реализован, но почему-то скрыт от широкой общественности. [Подробнее об этом здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle)

К счастью есть такая либа как [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/), в котором это можно относительно легко сделать.

Но опять же к несчастью, напрямую использовать Bouncy Castle в Android нельзя так как Google по неизвестным причинам его уже использует в коде Android, но в каком то урезанном виде, так что 90% Bouncy Castle неработоспособны. То есть при попытке включить библиотеку Bouncy Castle в ваш код, будет выдана ошибка о задвоении.

Опять же к счастью (мир не без добрых людей) - умные люди написали [Spongy Castle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) - специальный порт Bouncy Castle для Android'а который избавлен от конфликта имен.

Ну вот теперь:

1. Импортируем Spongy Castle через Gradle
2. Читаем [как генерировать сертификат](https://medium.com/@bouhady/self-sign-certificate-creation-using-spongy-castle-for-android-app-61f1545dd63#.jeh1g91om)

**P.S.** Уффф... зачем я так много написал? Наверное в честь пятницы